# Hotels in Yam Hamelach with Kosher Swimming

Tags: women, eretz-yisrael, travel, men-male, swimming

Can I get a list of Hotels in the Yam Hamelach (dead sea) area that feature separate swimming hours for men and women? Are there any?

Also looking for specific information on the Le Meridian ([here](http://www.starwoodhotels.com/lemeridien/property/overview/index.html?propertyID=1882)).

Offering a bounty -- the most hotels wins it...

Oh and including whether they serve Kosher (i.e. which hechsher) would be nice as well...

(prefer higher star-rating)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leonardo Club Dead Sea (Former Nirvana

Answer (score 0):

BINYAMIN BEACH : Separate beach facilities for men and women, snack bar, lockers, bathrooms and mud packs.
Tel: 02-942781 Not hotel but seprate